# Moar hats hats hats... - clarification for review hat

Tags: discussion, winterbash

I have some questions about hats. Unfortunately [a certain badp likes abusing me](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5641/revisions), so I will raise them as separate questions.

With the *5 Reviews* hat, is this 5 reviews of the same type, or 5 reviews spread across the 6 different categories of review?

Hat hat hat... ahem, Ho ho ho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's completing 5 review tasks of any type will earn you the badge. Some sites don't have enough edits or closures in one category, so it should be cumulative.

Comment: You're right - I've already got the hat but hadn't updated this post. :)